# Lines on different plane in a cube is parallel?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In this picture, are the blue circled lines are referred as parallel lines?
According to the definition for parallel lines, the lines should line on the same plane. Please clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In three-dimensional Euclidean space, parallel lines not only fail to intersect, but also maintain a constant separation between points closest to each other on the two lines. Therefore, parallel lines in three-space lie in a single plane. 
Source : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelLines.html

In this case, the plane is cutting the cube diagonally from near bottom to far top.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the same plane.  It's just a different plane from one of the planes you are thinking.  You probably have the faces of the cube in mind as the planes. But think of cutting the cube diagonally with a knife - starting from one blue edge and ending at the other blue edge.  Then the "tilted" plane through which your knife traveled is the one you are looking for.